# Getting button x y params

Tags: wpf, button

What would be the best way to get `Button` parameters when my `Button` is in an array?

```
class myButtonproprties
{
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Where I use it as:

```
myButtonproprties array[][];
```

I am new to WPF and I have heard about the `DependencyProperty` mechanism and didn't understand it.

Would it be helpful here?

**EDIT:**

Let's say I am already bound to a collection and then I want my logic to work for example:

```
<Button Text="{Binding Path=byttonInfo}"
        Width="50" 
        Height="50">
```

I want the `Button` to be with no text on it and to use button informaion as my logic.  Let's say my game is checkmate and every piece holds information when the `Button` is clicked.  I want to know who he is in order for my code behind logic to decide if he should move.

If he does what should I do then if I change is picture would the UI handle it?  In which thread?

You can see my motivation to this question here:
[memory card game wpf problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871467/memory-card-game-wpf-problem)

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @SLaks I edit my question i hope ot's more resonable now

Answer (score 0):

If your question means "How do I bind to a models' property when it is in an indexed collection?" then the answer is simple.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myButtonCollection[0][1].X}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myButtonCollection[0][1].Y}" />
```

WPF binding allows indexed binding to collections, eg. Lists, arrays, dictionaries.

If this is not your answer, then you need to word your question better.