# how and where to use DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I am new to WPF so after reading for a while I deduce that my problem needs to be handled with this pattern: `DependencyProperty`.

I want my `ToggleButton` to have another boolean property.

My problem is where should I assign this property, and how?  Inside the object that is bound to the `ToggleButton`?

Let's say I have a class cell (which is bound to this `Button`) that when clicked I want that from this point on, it would hold new face with trigger on.

My new property will be:

```
 bool wasClick
```

Can someone explain to me how I should write it and tell me more about this new concept?

**EDIT:**
The main topic is where should I define it so I want it asoocited to a `Button` but where should I write the code.  Lets say I have a class that is bound to a `Button`.  Should I write:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register(
...    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean),
```

in this class or should I write it in my view model?  If so, where and how?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about dependency properties?  Have you tried reading the MSDN articles on Dependency Properties? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx and all the other resource available all over the internet?

Comment: i didnt see a straight example for how and a simple motivation to why
and i thoght maybe if i would start building somthing while building it i would learn but i didnt see' understood any example showen in my google serch .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies (kind of poorly), a dependency property is a property whose value can depend on something else.  Generally, this means a property whose value gets determined automatically (and dynamically) by the WPF framework under certain conditions.  The most common conditions are:

- The property has a default value, or inherits its value from an ancestor in the visual tree.  In this case, the property's value is determined without it ever being set.
- The property is the target of data binding.
- The property's value is set by an animation.

Not all properties whose value gets set by the WPF framework need to be dependency properties.  Any CLR property with a public getter and setter can be the source of a two-way data binding.

In your case, it sounds like you don't really need a dependency property, not if you're using a view model.  You could just do this (assuming that you've implemented property-change notification in your class):

```
private bool _IsChecked;

public bool IsChecked
{
   get { return _IsChecked; } }
   set
   {
      if (value == _IsChecked)
      {
         return;
      }
      _IsChecked = value;
      WasChecked = WasChecked || value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
   }
}

private bool _WasChecked;

public bool WasChecked
{
   get { return _WasChecked; }
   private set
   {
      if (value == _WasChecked)
      {
         return;
      }
      _WasChecked = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("WasChecked");
   }
}
```

Comment: so i could go in the xaml and do :<Trigger Property="IWasChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="star1" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>

?????
                    <Setter TargetName="star2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>

Comment: i allready used it's defult proprty : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871467/memory-card-game-wpf-problem
I need another proprty

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.